# Summarize using multiple columns in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In R, I can summarize the data using more than one data columns as follows:
library(dplyr):

```
A =  B %>%
group_by(col1,col2) %>%
summarize(newcol = sum(col3)/sum(col4))
```

But in python's pandas' dataframes, how do I perform the same operation in one step?

I can do this in two steps.
Step 1:

```
A = B.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3': 'sum','col4':'sum'})
```

Step 2:

```
A['newcol'] = A['col3']/A['col4']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use assign with a lambda expression:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('aaabbb'), 
                   'col2': list('xyxyxy'), 
                   'col3': np.random.randn(6), 
                   'col4': np.random.randn(6)})

df
Out: 
  col1 col2      col3      col4
0    a    x -2.276155  0.323778
1    a    y -0.367525 -2.570142
2    a    x -0.672530  2.265560
3    b    y  0.588741  0.193499
4    b    x -1.368829  0.717997
5    b    y  1.012271  1.354408

(df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
   .agg({'col3': 'sum','col4':'sum'})
   .assign(newcol=lambda x: x['col3']/x['col4']))
Out: 
               col4      col3    newcol
col1 col2                              
a    x     2.589338 -2.948686 -1.138780
     y    -2.570142 -0.367525  0.142998
b    x     0.717997 -1.368829 -1.906453
     y     1.547907  1.601012  1.034308
```

If all you need is the new column, use apply:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).apply(lambda x: x['col3'].sum() / x['col4'].sum())
Out: 
col1  col2
a     x      -1.138780
      y       0.142998
b     x      -1.906453
      y       1.034308
dtype: float64
```

If you are using this on a big data set, avoid apply and use eval instead.

```
(df.groupby(['col1','col2'])
   .agg({'col3': 'sum','col4':'sum'})
   .eval('col3 / col4'))
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), you can do it the same way you did in R:

```py
from datar import f
from datar.base import sum
from datar.dplyr import group_by, summarise

A =  (
  B 
  >> group_by(f.col1,f.col2) 
  >> summarize(newcol = sum(f.col3)/sum(f.col4))
)
```